# Smallest number whose $\sin(x)$ in radian and degrees is equal

Tags: trigonometry

Question:

> What is the smallest positive real number $x$ with the property that the sine of $x$ degrees is equal to the sine of $x$ radians?

My try: 0. But zero isn't a positive number. How do I even begin to solve it? I tried taking inverse on both sides of $\sin \theta = \sin x$, but that didn't help.

Comment: You might start by thinking what you can say about $x,y$ (both in radians) if $\sin x=\sin y$.

Comment: Well, then x and y must be equal. So I guess that the number would be very small?

Comment: No. Eg $x=y+2\pi$ or $x=\pi-y$.

Comment: I didn't get that.

Comment: What is $\sin150^o$? What is $\sin30^o$?

Comment: Same value: 1/2.

Comment: But both the numbers in this case are measured in different units, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One degree is $\frac{\pi}{180}$ radians, so what we want here is
$$\sin(x)=\sin(\frac{\pi x}{180})$$
And so
$$x = \frac{\pi x}{180}+2\pi k, \qquad \text{or} \qquad x = \frac{-\pi x}{180}+\pi (2k+1)$$
Where $k$ is any integer (since $\sin(a) = \sin(b)$ iff $a-b$ is an integer multiple of $2\pi$, or if $a+b$ is an odd multiple of $\pi$). Solving for $x$,
$$x(1 - \frac{\pi}{180}) = 2\pi k, \qquad \text{or} \qquad x(1 + \frac{\pi}{180}) = \pi (2k+1)$$
And now we just need to find the $k$ that gives us the smallest positive solution. Since the number on the left hand side is positive (in both cases), we choose $k = 1$ for the left, and $k = 0$ for the right. Then
$$x = \frac{2\pi}{1-\frac{\pi}{180}}, \qquad \text{or} \qquad x = \frac{\pi}{1+\frac{\pi}{180}}$$
The right hand solution is smaller, so that's our answer.

Answer (score 1):

We have

$$\sin (x) = \sin (\beta x)$$

where $\beta := \frac{\pi}{180}$. Using

$$\sin (\alpha x) = \frac{e^{i \alpha x} - e^{-i \alpha x}}{2i}$$

we conclude that the equation $\sin (x) = \sin (\beta x)$ can be rewritten as follows

$$2 \, \sin \left( \left(\frac{1-\beta}{2}\right) x\right) \, \cos \left( \left(\frac{1+\beta}{2}\right) x\right) = 0$$

The smallest positive solution is, thus,

$$\min \left( \frac{2\pi}{1-\beta}, \frac{\pi}{1+\beta} \right) = \min \left( \frac{2\pi}{1-\frac{\pi}{180}}, \frac{\pi}{1+\frac{\pi}{180}} \right) = \frac{\pi}{1+\frac{\pi}{180}} = \left(\frac{1}{\pi}+\frac{1}{180}\right)^{-1}$$